# It's a logarithmic worksheet and O can't solve it.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_ax=p$, $\log_bx=q$ ,    $\log_{abc}x$=r. What is  $\log_cx$?.. It's on my math homework can someone solve it cause I need it.

Comment: if you're satisfied with any of the answers, then you should probably accept whichever one you thought was most helpful (it is a form of reward for us answering your question).

Answer (score 1):

So, use the log change of basis formula:

$\log(x)/\log(a) = p \\ \log(x)/\log(b) = q \\ \log(x)/\log(abc) = (\frac{\log(a)+\log(b)+\log(c)}{\log(x)})^{-1} = r$

and so $\log(x)/\log(c) = (\frac{\log(c)}{\log(x)})^{-1} = (\frac{\log(a)+\log(b)+\log(c)}{\log(x)} - \frac{\log(b)}{\log(x)} - \frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)})^{-1} = (\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{p})^{-1}$

Comment: @dona12, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

let $w =\log_cx$

$a^p=x,b^q=x,(abc)^r=x$. but $(abc)^r=a^r*b^r*c^r=a^{p*\frac{r}{p}}*b^{q*\frac{r}{q}}*c^{w*\frac{r}{w}}=x^{\frac{r}{p}}*x^{\frac{r}{q}}*x^{\frac{r}{w}}=x^{\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}+\frac{r}{w}}=x^1=x$

Therefore $\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}+\frac{r}{w}=1 \rightarrow \frac{r}{w}=1-\frac{r}{p}-\frac{r}{q}\rightarrow r=w(1-\frac{r}{p}-\frac{r}{q})\rightarrow w=\frac{r}{1-\frac{r}{p}-\frac{r}{q}}=\frac{p q r}{p q-p r-q r} $

Answer (score 1):

Using

**Change of Base Formula:**

$$\log_ax = \frac{\log_bx}{\log_ba}$$

And **Product:**

$$\log_a (xy) = \log_ax + \log_ay$$

And

$$\log_aa = 1$$

---

You have:
$$\log_{abc} x = \frac{log_x x}{\log_x abc} = \frac{1}{\log_x abc} = r$$

$$\log_a x = \frac{\log_x x}{\log_x a} = \frac{1}{\log_x a} = p \implies \log_x a = \frac{1}{p}$$

$$\log_b x = \frac{\log_x x}{\log_x b} = \frac{1}{\log_x b} = q \implies \log_x b = \frac{1}{q}$$
So substituting what you have from above:
$$\frac{1}{\log_x abc} = \frac{1}{\log_x a + \log_x b + \log_x c} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \log_x c} =r$$

$$1 =r \left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \log_x c\right)$$

$$\frac{1 -\frac{r}{p} - \frac{r}{q}}{r} = \log_x c$$

Following from above

$$\log_cx = \frac{1}{\log_xc} = \frac{1}{\frac{1 -\frac{r}{p} - \frac{r}{q}}{r}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}$$

Can also be expressed as $$\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}\right)^{-1}$$